# How to display reports in dashboard ms dynamic crm 2015

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dynamic-reports

I have tried webresource and iframe way to display reports in dasboard but screen is blank in 2015 crm.Please find the blog links which i used to display  reports:

https://reportingondashboard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ReportControl.html

http://weblogs.asp.net/pabloperalta/how-to-display-a-report-in-a-dashboard-in-dynamics-crm-2011

I am not able to get it.Please let me know how to display reports in dashboards 2015 ms crm

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having issues with this, I've been doing the same type of work with CRM 2013 and using the same type of WebResources.  What I have found is that the onload assignment in the  tag gets erased when the WebResource is saved.  What you'll need to do is at the end of the script section, add:

```
window.addEventListener("load",<name of function from <body> tag>)
```

Then save and try it again.  This helped me get the report to actually run but I'm now running into an issue where the report is only showing the first 3 lines and does not give me any scroll options.  Would love to find a way to fix that.